# $x^2-y^2-1$ irreducible in $K[x,y]$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Being $K$ any field, I am trying to figure out if $x^2-y^2-1$ is irreducible in $K[x,y]$.

My approach was to assume there is a decomposition $x^2-y^2-1=(ax+by+c)(ex+fy+g)$ and try to reach a contradiction. At some point doing this, I reach that the equation $b^2+c^2=0$ must be satisfied. If $K$ were, for example, $\mathbb{R}$, from this I could conclude that $b=c=0$ and that allows me to reach later a contradiction. But since $K$ could be any field, I do not think I can do that.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to easily prove whether this polynomial is irreducible?

Comment: If $K=\Bbb{F}_2$ then we have $x^2-y^2-1=(x+y+1)^2$. Unless we are in characteristic two, it looks like it is irreducible.

Comment: You can use the techniques described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/96400/11619) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2666269/11619), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2109372/11619),... Or even [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/486668/11619).

Answer (score 1):

Let's regard the polynomial is in $y$ and $x$ is in the coefficient ring. Eisenstein's criterion can be applied to the prime $x+1$ as long as the prime ideals $(x+1)$ and $(x-1)$ are distinct. Thus, it is irreducible if char $K$ $\neq 2.$